# Bar plot with polar axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, polar-coordinates

I want to make my plot similar to this-

[image]

Currently, what I am able to get is this:

[image]

I am not able to do the following things:

1. Get the time labels inside the inner circle
2. Get the ticks inside the circle. This question - [How to create minor ticks for polar plot matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44657003/2650427), had an idea which I tried but it was messing up with other parts of the plot.
3. Time labels only work properly when the step size is 3. For other steps, it does not align with the bars.

Below is the reproducible code to produce the plot

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 24, size = 50000)
df = pd.DataFrame({"COL": arr}).COL.value_counts().sort_index()

N = 24
bottom = 1000
theta, width = np.linspace(0.0, 2 * np.pi, N, endpoint=False, retstep=True)

plt.figure(figsize = (10, 6))
ax = plt.subplot(111, polar=True)

bars = ax.bar(
    theta, df,
    width=width-0.03,
    bottom=bottom,
    color="#f39c12", edgecolor="black"
)
bars = ax.bar(
    theta, [3000]*24,
    width=width-0.03,
    bottom=bottom,
    color="#f39c12", alpha=0.2
)

ax.set_theta_zero_location("N")
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.grid(False)
ax.spines['polar'].set_visible(False)
ax.set_rticks([])

ticks = [f"{i}:00" for i in range(0, 24, 3)]
ax.set_xticklabels(ticks)

_ = ax
```

Comment: You should spend time working your way through the [Tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/index.html#tutorials) - at least up to and including the Artist tutorial. Matplotlib is very *configurable*, working through the Tutorials will give you an understanding of how it works and will make it easier to adapt examples from [The Gallery](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/index.html).

Comment: At first glance: create an image of the clock-face; add it to the center of the plot.

Comment: Thanks for the tutorial link. I'll go through it. I was hoping I could make the plot through matplotlib only. I don't specifically want the clock. What I want is just the ticks and the time labels inside.

Comment: The polar axes have no "inner spine" or "inner Axes". So one option is to create your custom projection for this purpose, which does have those inner axes, but this is surely not easy. Alternatively you need to position some `text` labels and lines manually. The question you link to shows that partially. So it might be a good idea to start with that.

Comment: I did that, but the ticks were not showing up properly inside. It was working as expected as shown in the answer but when I changed the line segment positions for inner circle, it did not work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I just drew two lines and a circle to make the "clock icon"

```
## Draw a "clock" icon inside of the graph
##lines for hands of a clock
x1, y1 = [0, 90], [0, 0.5*bottom]
x2, y2 = [0,0], [0, 0.5*bottom]
plt.plot(x1, y1, x2, y2, linewidth=2.5, solid_capstyle='round', color='#0066ff', alpha=1)

##circle for clockface
circle = pl.Circle((0, 0), 0.65*bottom, transform=ax.transData._b, linewidth=3, fill=False, color="#0066ff", alpha=1)
ax.add_artist(circle)
```

did you ever figure out how to write the numbers inside of the clock?

Answer (score 0):

Also if you wanna add the numbers inside of the circle do this:

```
#00, 06, 12, 18 labels for clockface
plt.text(0, bottom*.80, "00", transform=ax.transData._b, ha='center', va='center', color='black', fontsize=2.5, fontweight='bold')
plt.text(bottom*.80, 0, "06", transform=ax.transData._b, ha='center', va='center', color='black', fontsize=2.5, fontweight='bold')
plt.text(0, -bottom*.80, "12", transform=ax.transData._b, ha='center', va='center', color='black', fontsize=2.5, fontweight='bold')
plt.text(-bottom*.80, 0, "18", transform=ax.transData._b, ha='center', va='center', color='black', fontsize=2.5, fontweight='bold')
```

I know it's not the best or fanciest way to do this but it works OK! Please @ me if you have a cleaner way to write this code haha..

Also some other notes:

-For the code i posted above change the sizes of the hour and minute hand to make it look even better (multiply bottom variable by  different values below 1)

-I had to change the fontsize, and linewidths as I changed the size and dpi of the image to make it look right but its not too hard to figure out how to make it look right.

-I ended up not drawing the tick marks as it didn't seem worth my time to figure out how to do it. would love to know from anyone else if there's some way to space out dashes or something around there. But i really just didn't wanna mess with the rotation